# How to get cache_cluster_id from elasticache using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-elasticache

I'd like to get elasticache cache_cluster_id in order to populate a jinja2 template.

I'm using boto to get some stuff from the API, such as ec2 instances or elb data but for elasticache it seems more difficult.

```
import boto.elasticache

conn = boto.elasticache.connect_to_region(region)
elasticache_data = conn.describe_cache_clusters()
```

That's what I manage to get, but I'm not sure to understand how I can loop through cache_cluster_id to get all the data I need.

ref: http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/elasticache.html

The api answer looks like that:

```
> {u'DescribeCacheClustersResponse': 
>     {u'ResponseMetadata': 
>         {u'RequestId': u'ID'}, 
>      u'DescribeCacheClustersResult': 
>            {u'Marker': None, 
>            u'CacheClusters': 
>                 [
>                     {u'Engine': u'redis', u'CacheParameterGroup': 
>                         {u'CacheNodeIdsToReboot': [], 
>                         u'CacheParameterGroupName': u'default', 
>                         u'ParameterApplyStatus': u'in-sync'},
>                      u'CacheClusterId': u'whatever', 
>                      u'CacheSecurityGroups': [], 
>                      u'ConfigurationEndpoint': None, 
>                      u'CacheClusterCreateTime': 1415217879.493, 
>                      u'ReplicationGroupId': u'whatever', 
>                      u'AutoMinorVersionUpgrade': True, 
>                      u'CacheClusterStatus': u'available', 
>                      u'NumCacheNodes': 1, 
>                      u'ClientDownloadLandingPage': u'https://console.aws.amazon.com...', 
>                      u'PreferredAvailabilityZone': u'us-east-1a', 
>                      u'SecurityGroups': [{u'Status': u'active', u'SecurityGroupId': u'123'}],   
>                      u'CacheSubnetGroupName': u'whatever',
>                      u'EngineVersion': u'2.8.6', 
>                      u'PendingModifiedValues': 
>                         {u'NumCacheNodes': None, 
>                         u'EngineVersion': None,
>                         u'CacheNodeIdsToRemove': None}, 
>                      u'CacheNodeType': u'cache.m1.small', 
>                      u'NotificationConfiguration': None, 
>                      u'PreferredMaintenanceWindow': 
>                      u'sat:04:30-sat:05:30', 
>                      u'CacheNodes': None
>                     }
>                 ]
>             }
>     } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's the proper way of doing it... but it seems to work for my need.
If someone have a better way of doing it please let me know.

```
import boto.elasticache

conn = boto.elasticache.connect_to_region(region)
data = conn.describe_cache_clusters()
clusters = data["DescribeCacheClustersResponse"]["DescribeCacheClustersResult"]["CacheClusters"]

for value in clusters:
    print value["CacheClusterId"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3


conn = boto3.client('elasticache')

data = conn.describe_cache_clusters()
#print(data)
#print(data['CacheClusters'])

for r in data['CacheClusters']:
    #print(r)
    db_engine = r["Engine"]
    print(db_engine)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.